# why and when is 'implicitly' required

Tags: scala

I'm trying to understand the use of the 'implicitly' operation:

```
class foo {
  def x : Int = 12
}

object foo {
  implicit def intToFoo(x : Int ) : foo = new foo
}

object bar {
   implicitly[foo](1).x
}
```

The above compiles. But I can't work out why the 'implicitly' operation is required. It seems to me that because the 'destination companion object' includes the implicit conversion, it should automatically happen.

Answer (score 2):

One of the more common uses for `implicitly` (that I've seen) is when employing [context bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html) type parameters.

Recall that a type parameter can be restricted to a type class by requiring "evidence":

```
def f[N](n :N)(implicit ev :Numeric[N]) :Boolean = ???
```

This can be made cleaner by using context bound syntax.

```
def f[N :Numeric](n: N) :Boolean = ???
```

But now we don't have `ev`, the implicit parameter, to work with. This isn't always a problem. Often you need the type restriction but you don't need the evidence parameter. But if you do need the parameter then one way around the problem is to pull it in via `implicitly`.

```
def f[N :Numeric](n: N) :Boolean = {
  val nn = implicitly[Numeric[N]].negate(n)
  . . .
}
```

This adds a bit of overhead since the implicit is resolved twice, once as the (now hidden) implicit parameter and once again via `implicitly`, but if you want the clean context bound syntax, and only need the implicit parameter once or twice, it is sometimes seen as a worthwhile trade off.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really required here. You could also get away with

```
object bar {
   import foo._
   1.x
}
```

because importing `foo._` would also bring the implicit conversion into the implicit scope, so that `1` would be wrapped into a `foo` automatically, thereby "acquiring" the method `x`.

The usage of `implicitly` in your code is rather uncommon, because it is essentially just a replacement for a type ascription:

```
object bar {
   (1: foo).x
}
```

The type ascription works too, because now you again mention that you expect `1` to be of type `foo`, and therefore the compiler will search in the implicit scope of `foo` for a suitable implicit conversion.

Even if you don't import any implicit conversions, your code does not rely on `implicitly` in any significant way. The same would happen with any other function that requires a `foo`:
    import  scala.language.implicitConversions

```
class foo {
  def x : Int = 12
}

object foo {
  implicit def intToFoo(x : Int ) : foo = new foo
}

def randomOtherFunction(a: foo, i: Int): foo = a

object bar {
  randomOtherFunction(1, 42).x
}
```

Here, just as in your example with `implicitly`, the function `randomOtherFunction` requires a `foo` as first argument. Since `Int` is not a `foo`, the compiler goes on to search for an applicable implicit conversion from `Int` to `foo`. One of the places where it looks is the companion object of `foo`. Therefore, the compiler inserts `intToFoo`:

```
  randomOtherFunction(intToFoo(1), 42).x
```

and everything compiles.

Comment: I guess my question is why do I have to explicitly import foo._ -- since it is the companion object of the destination type, should the conversion not automatically be in scope?

Comment: @MichaelWrighton `bar` has nothing to do with `foo`, why should it be in scope? You either have to `import foo._`, or you have to introduce some kind of function with argument list that expects a `foo`. Otherwise, the code in `bar` will not look at `foo` at all, even though it cannot make any sense of `1.x` otherwise.